# Resources for improving algebra skills?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I took my first calculus test today and my experience during that test confirmed my fears leading up to the test: I'm terrible at Algebra. One of my weakest areas is factoring. Can you give me some resources to help me improve my Algebra skills? Thank you so much!

Comment: umm.. open a book on precalculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Khan Academy can be very helpful with many subjects and it turns out they have a video that explains factoring too: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/factoring-quadratic-expressions/v/factoring-quadratic-expressions

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment.

Comment: They asked for resources and I provided an answer with a resource.